Как сделать чтобы когда navbar сворачивается/разворачивается отображение другого компонента корректным?
Нужно сделать отображение другого компонента, например формы заполнения корректным. Ибо navbar может перекрывать его и т.п. Это надо как-то передавать состояние navbar или как?
Еще проблема, когда открывается navbar то элементы (categories) смещаются чуть ниже...
Код компонента navbar:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    CssBaseline,
    Drawer,
    List,
    ListItemButton,
    ListItemIcon,
    ListItemText,
    Typography,
    Box,
    Collapse,
    Divider,
    Button,
} from "@mui/material";
import ShareIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Share';
import CalendarMonthIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonth';
import QueryStatsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/QueryStats';
import {
    ExpandLess,
    ExpandMore,
    Liquor as LiquorIcon,
    LibraryBooks as LibraryBooksIcon,
    Settings as SettingsIcon,
    Logout as LogoutIcon,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const Navbar = () => {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
    const [openCategories, setOpenCategories] = useState({});
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("");

    const drawerWidthCollapsed = 80;
    const drawerWidthExpanded = 300;

    const darkTheme = createTheme({
        palette: {
            mode: "dark",
            primary: {
                main: "#313131",
            },
            secondary: {
                main: "#f990d8",
            },
        },
        typography: {
            fontFamily: "JetBrains Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        },
    });

    const categories = [
        {
            title: "Администрирование",
            items: [
                { text: "Аналитика", icon: <QueryStatsIcon /> },
                { text: "Расписание", icon: <CalendarMonthIcon /> },
                {
                    text: "Отчётность",
                    icon: <LibraryBooksIcon />,
                    subItems: ["Текущая смена", "Бар"],
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            title: "Управление",
            items: [
                {
                    text: "Бар",
                    icon: <LiquorIcon />,
                    subItems: ["Лимиты", "Склад"],
                },
                {
                    text: "Интеграции",
                    icon: <ShareIcon />,
                    subItems: ["Telegram", "Колесо фортуны"],
                },
                {
                    text: "Настройки",
                    icon: <SettingsIcon />,
                    subItems: ["Сотрудники", "Расписание"],
                },
            ],
        },
    ];

    const toggleCategory = (index) => {
        setOpenCategories((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [index]: !prevState[index],
        }));
    };

    const handleTabClick = (tabName) => {
        setActiveTab(tabName);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isExpanded) {
            setOpenCategories({});
        }
    }, [isExpanded]);

    const handleLogout = () => {
        console.log("Logout clicked");
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Drawer
                variant="permanent"
                anchor="left"
                onMouseEnter={() => setIsExpanded(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setIsExpanded(false)}
                sx={{
                    width: isExpanded ? drawerWidthExpanded : drawerWidthCollapsed,
                    transition: "width 0.3s ease",
                    [`& .MuiDrawer-paper`]: {
                        width: isExpanded ? drawerWidthExpanded : drawerWidthCollapsed,
                        boxSizing: "border-box",
                        backgroundColor: darkTheme.palette.background.default,
                        color: darkTheme.palette.text.primary,
                        overflowX: "hidden",
                        transition: "width 0.3s ease",
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                        height: "100vh",
                    },
                }}
            >
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        display: "flex",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        minHeight: "80px", // Минимальная высота для блока с логотипом
                        padding: "16px",
                        marginBottom: "20px",
                    }}
                >
                    <Typography
                        variant="h4"
                        noWrap
                        sx={{
                            fontWeight: 600,
                            letterSpacing: "1px",
                            fontSize: "24px",
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            gap: isExpanded ? "8px" : "0px",
                            transition: "gap 0.3s ease",
                        }}
                    >
                        <span
                            style={{
                                background: "linear-gradient(to right, #30cfd0, #90caf9)",
                                WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
                                WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
                                fontSize: isExpanded ? "42px" : "32px",
                                transition: "font-size 0.3s ease",
                            }}
                        >
                            {isExpanded ? "Serve" : "S"}
                        </span>
                        {isExpanded && (
                            <span
                                style={{
                                    background: "linear-gradient(to right, #f76c6c, #fcb69f)",
                                    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
                                    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
                                    fontSize: "24px",
                                    position: "relative",
                                    top: "-10px",
                                }}
                            >
                                {`{Report}`}
                            </span>
                        )}
                    </Typography>
                </Box>

                <List sx={{ padding: "24px", flexGrow: 1, overflowY: "auto" }}>
                    {categories.map((category, catIndex) => (
                        <div key={catIndex}>
                            {isExpanded && (
                                <Typography
                                    variant="h6"
                                    sx={{
                                        fontSize: "12px",
                                        padding: "8px 16px",
                                        fontWeight: "350",
                                        color: darkTheme.palette.text.secondary,
                                        marginBottom: "2px",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {category.title}
                                </Typography>
                            )}
                            <Divider sx={{ marginBottom: "8px" }} />
                            {category.items.map((item, index) => (
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <ListItemButton
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            handleTabClick(item.text);
                                            if (item.subItems) {
                                                toggleCategory(`${catIndex}-${index}`);
                                            }
                                        }}
                                        sx={{
                                            marginBottom: "12px",
                                            borderRadius: "12px",
                                            justifyContent: isExpanded ? "flex-start" : "center",
                                            padding: isExpanded ? "8px 12px" : "8px",
                                            backgroundColor: activeTab === item.text ? "#2c2c2c" : "transparent",
                                            "&:hover": {
                                                backgroundColor: darkTheme.palette.primary.main,
                                                color: "#fff",
                                            },
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <ListItemIcon
                                            sx={{
                                                color: "inherit",
                                                minWidth: isExpanded ? "30px" : "unset",
                                                display: "flex",
                                                justifyContent: "center",
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {item.icon}
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                overflow: "hidden",
                                                height: isExpanded ? "auto" : "0px",
                                                display: isExpanded ? "block" : "none",
                                                opacity: isExpanded ? 1 : 0,
                                                transition: "opacity 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease",
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
                                        </Box>
                                        {item.subItems &&
                                            isExpanded &&
                                            (openCategories[`${catIndex}-${index}`] ? (
                                                <ExpandLess />
                                            ) : (
                                                <ExpandMore />
                                            ))}
                                    </ListItemButton>

                                    {item.subItems && (
                                        <Collapse
                                            in={openCategories[`${catIndex}-${index}`]}
                                            timeout="auto"
                                            unmountOnExit
                                            sx={{
                                                "& .MuiListItemButton-root": {
                                                    opacity: openCategories[`${catIndex}-${index}`] ? 1 : 0,
                                                    transform: openCategories[`${catIndex}-${index}`] ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(-10px)",
                                                    transition: "opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease",
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <List component="div" disablePadding>
                                                {item.subItems.map((subItem, subIndex) => (
                                                    <ListItemButton
                                                        key={subIndex}
                                                        sx={{
                                                            pl: 4,
                                                            borderRadius: "8px",
                                                            margin: "4px 8px",
                                                            "&:hover": {
                                                                backgroundColor: "#2c2c2c",
                                                            },
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        <ListItemText primary={subItem} />
                                                    </ListItemButton>
                                                ))}
                                            </List>
                                        </Collapse>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </List>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        bottom: 0,
                        width: "100%",
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        padding: "16px",
                    }}
                >
                    <Button
                        variant="text"
                        color="secondary"
                        startIcon={isExpanded ? <LogoutIcon /> : null}
                        onClick={handleLogout}
                        sx={{
                            color: "#ff4f4f",
                            justifyContent: isExpanded ? "flex-start" : "center",
                            width: isExpanded ? "100%" : "auto",
                            padding: isExpanded ? "8px 12px" : "8px",
                            "&:hover": {
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,116,116,0.15)",
                            },
                            transition: "all 0.3s ease",
                        }}
                    >
                        {isExpanded ? "Выйти" : <LogoutIcon />}
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Drawer>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default Navbar;

